# Match until last occurrence of, but if not exists - match to end of string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to construct a regex to match a part of a string, starting from a certain string, and until the last occurrence of a string, unless that string doesn't exist - in which case the rest of the string should match.

Some inputs I'm trying to match:

```
i_123_Mobile
i_123_abc_Mobile
i_123aa_abcdaeedg_Desktop
i_abc123
```

Expected output:

```
123
123_abc
123aa_abcdaeedg
abc123
```

The following regex works for the first three, but not for the fourth ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Im2mq/1)):

```
(?<=i_).*(?=_)
```

Although I can just use an `|` operator:

```
(?<=i_).*(?=_)|(?<=i_).*$
```

I'd like to learn if there's a way to not repeat myself (note the `(?<=i_)` repeats)?

Comment: `(?<=^i_)(?:.*(?=_)|.*$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nXCmkn/1)

Comment: This works fine: [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/fr/regex-tester/6c9498884af8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine your two alternatives after the one element that would be repeated:

```
(?<=i_)(?:.*(?=_)|.*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWdSkf/1)

Or without the lookahead works too if you don't mind the trailing `_` as part of the match:

```
(?<=i_)(?:.*_|.*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0nOBV/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can match as few chars as possible with `.*?` instead of a greedy dot **and** restrict the `_` in the lookahead to only match the last underscore symbol:

```
(?<=i_).*?(?=(?:_[^_]*)?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gqnCJF/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=i_)` - a position immediately after `i_` substring
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars (other than line break chars) as few as possible
- `(?=(?:_[^_]*)?$)` - immediately to the right, there should be an optional occurrence of a `_` followed with zero or more chars other than `_` and then the end of string should follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert matches of the regular expression

```
^.*?_|_[^_]*$
```

to empty strings.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cY2ggT/1)

Notice that this works for languages whose regex engine does not support lookarounds, such as Go (aka Golang).

We have

```
^       match the beginning of the string
.*?     match zero or more characters other than line terminators,
        as few as possible
_       match literal
|       or
_       match literal
[^_]*   match zero or more characters other than '_'
$       match end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *match pattern*.

```
(?<=i_).+?(?=_[^_]+$|$)
```

And, a *capture pattern*.

```
i_(.+?)(?:_[^_]+$|$)
```